# Set the region format setting to "Match Windows display language" programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, registry

I'm looking for a way to set this option by using a batch or PS script. 
While adding a new language to the registry key is super easy `REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v LocaleName /d en-EN /f` I didn't find any references on how to set the key to match the display language. I assume that this is a Windows Feature only and not bound to a key.

[image]

So do I really need to read out the Display Language Key `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages"` first or is my assumption wrong and their really is a universal key to set it to the display language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if there is a Registry key for that, but there is a Powershell cmdlet to change it.

```
Set-WinCultureFromLanguageListOptOut 0
```

Sets it to "Match Windows Display language (recommended)". 
This is also the Default.

```
Set-WinCultureFromLanguageListOptOut 1
```

Sets it to what ever language you have currently enabled, e.g. English (United States).

Look here for more on that cmdlet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj136913.aspx

And here for the other cmdlets regarding international Settings: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems I really need to work on my Powershell skills and get away from Batch.

Comment: I am glad I could help and I am often surprised too on how many useful Powershell cmdlets there are that make scripting things a lot easier.